# Build Artifacts Keyboard shortcut for IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I've searched the web and haven't been able to find a good answer to this. I'm looking for a keyboard shortcut for building artifacts in IntelliJ.

There is the Ctrl + F9 key that builds the project, but what about building artifacts? I can't find a shortcut for it online.

All help is appreciated.

Note: 
I use IntelliJ 2019.1.2 (Ultimate)
My OS is Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa

Comment: It's possible to set shortcut for "Build Artifacts" action in "Settings/Preferences | Keymap"

Comment: Thanks, if you post that as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to set shortcut for "Build Artifacts" action in "Settings/Preferences | Keymap"